# Run video in SWT application?

Tags: video, swt

I wish to run a video in a SWT application on Windows. Do you think this is possible first of all? If yes, what technologies do you suggest?

Thank you very much and regards,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do this quite natively. I used the SWT AWT bridge and played the video using JMF on AWT hence being able to see it in SWT.

Answer (score 4):

Hmnnn... I'd probably create an SWT composite with an embedded browser and run your video in that embedded browser.  That way, you can simply leverage the browser's video rendering capability.

```
public class BrowserComposite extends Composite {
  private Browser _browser;

  public BrowserComposite(Composite parent) {
    super(parent, SWT.NONE);
    setLayout(new FillLayout());
    _browser = new Browser(this, SWT.NONE);
  }
```

}

Now you can simply have the browser open say a Flash file or something.

FYI - the default Browser in Windows is IE, so if you want to use Mozilla you can pass Mozilla as the style bit.  Default for Mac is Safari - same thing to force Mozilla.

Comment: Why, after compiling, the browser writes that the video tag is not supported?